# plot different subplots with the windrose module

Tags: python, matplotlib, sleep, windrose, rose-plot

I am trying to plot wind roses in subplots by using the module windrose in python

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/windrose/

Apart from some examples there is not too much documentation so I do not know how to use it to plot different subplots of wind roses

My try quite summarized:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from windrose import WindroseAxes
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from time import sleep

v=df.speed
d=df.direction
f = Figure(figsize=(16,9), dpi=60) 
a = f.add_subplot(131)
ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
a.set_axes(ax)
ax.bar(d,v, normed= True,opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
ax.set_legend()
```

then `b = f.add_subplot(132)`
....
and so on

My second question is,

Once I generate the plot I would like to introduce a pause with time.sleep() or something similar

I tried with a simple example in which:

1. I plot something
2. then export it to png format with f.savefig()
3. then I introduce sleep(20)
4. then the code continues

but although it exports the right png It is not displayed on the screen and the code continues. As it does not raise any error I suppose there is something missing I should add before or after sleep()

Comment: Please ask two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

First question: You can not put another `figure` to existing `figure` as `subplot` (unfortunately `WindroseAxes.from_ax()` create a new `figure` and does not change only `axis` instance).

If you write

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9), dpi=60) 
wax = WindroseAxes.from_ax(fig=fig)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
wax.contourf(wd, ws, bins=np.arange(0, 8, 1), cmap=cm.hot)
wax.set_legend()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax2.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'k-')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax3.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,10,100,1000], 'b-')
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
ax4.plot([1,2,3,4], [0,0,1,1], 'g-')
```

You get something like this:
[image]

Second question: to redraw your plot you need to add `plt.draw()` after changing on a plot.
But if you  only want to make a set of images, just call `savefig` every time you need without `plt.show()`.